# ListView footer not center

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

Any idea why the footer of my list view is always on the left? Here's my xml layout. Footer just added and removed as more data needs loaded. I want theTextView and ProgressBar to be center

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="@color/author_text"
    android:text="LOADING DATA..."
    />

<ProgressBar 
    android:layout_width="15dp" 
    android:layout_height="15dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Note that the `ListView` provides methods for setting actual footers, [see this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)).

Comment: Okay, so the problem was NOT with the footer view shown in the OP; it indeed works just fine. The problem was my ListView had the layout_width attribute set to wrap_content. This works just fine for all the list renderers, but not for the footer. Changing the ListView to fill_parent fixed it

    <ListView 
  android:id="@+id/android:list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  style="@style/MyList"
  />


thanks gang
[SOLVED]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so the problem was NOT with the footer view shown in the OP; it indeed works just fine. The problem was my ListView had the layout_width attribute set to wrap_content. This works just fine for all the list renderers, but not for the footer. Changing the ListView to fill_parent fixed it

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    style="@style/MyList"
    />
```

thanks gang
[SOLVED]

Answer (score 1):

A horizontal LinearLayout will lay its views out left-to-right. It ignores any gravity or layout_gravity attributes when determining horizontal positioning (although these will affect vertical positioning). You'll need to use a RelativeLayout or else nest a vertical LinearLayout to get horizontal centering of views.

Alternatively, you could give the TextView a layout_weight of 1, which will cause it to take up any extra space. Since it will center its text, that should give you the effect you want.

EDIT: Now that I understand what you want, this ought to do it:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/author_text"
            android:text="LOADING DATA..."
            />

        <ProgressBar 
            android:layout_width="15dp" 
            android:layout_height="15dp" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can maybe avoid the nested LinearLayouts by using a RelativeLayout in some way, but this came to mind first.

Comment: Also, this works just fine if I inflate the layout directly into an activity, just not the listview footer. Thanks.

Comment: I was suggesting that you add `android:layout_weight="1"` to the TextView. This should push the ProgressBar all the way to the right and center the text horizontally in the remaining space. That's my understanding of what you are after, but I may have gotten it wrong.

Comment: I want the total width of TextView and Progress to be centered.

Answer (score 0):

try setting its layout_width to `match_parent`

Comment: targeting API 7, fill_parent is needed not match_parent. And which View did you mean?

Comment: `match_parent` and `fill_parent` are synonyms. Frankly, although there may have been good philosophical reasons to introduce a new name and deprecate the old, it's mostly been a nuisance.

Comment: I thought you were trying to center the text view, but I see you were trying to center that entire linearlayout. Setting the text view to `match_parent` and `layout_gravity` to `center` centered the text for me. I misunderstood your question.